# Eloquent way to filter by average of 2 columns

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a JobPosts table and I want to select all the records with average salary is greater then given value. I can do it by using raw query but I feel that I am missing something. My code:

```
$salary = 100000;
$query = JobPost::whereRaw('("salary_min" + "salary_max")/2 >= ' . $salary)->getQuery();
```

Can I do it without using raw query or in other better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$salary = 100000;
echo $query = JobPost::whereRaw($salary.' < (SELECT AVG(salary_min + salary_max ) FROM job_posts)')->get();
```

`job_posts` replace with your table name

Comment: Thx for the answer, but you code uses raw query too, I wanted to do it without using it. I'm afraid of SQL injections in my $salary variable. I can do some checking to ensure that $salary is definitely integer, but i wondered are there ways to do it without raw queries.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works have not touched Laravel in a while, but out of memory you should be able to do something like this:

```
$salary = 100000;
$query = JobPost::selectRaw('((salary_min + salary_max) / 2) as average')->where('average', '>', $salary)->getQuery();
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but you code uses raw query too, I wanted to do it without using it. I'm afraid of SQL injections in my $salary variable. I can do some checking to ensure that $salary is definitely integer, but i wondered are there ways to do it without raw queries.

Answer (score 0):

its easy bro

just try

controller code

```
   $salary = 100000; $query = JobPost::all();
  return view('--your blade file name--', compact('query'))
```

and write blade file this code . will get $avg either "display:block" or "display:none" . then apply $avg style for jobpost . so

if "display:none" means jobpost will hide else "display:block" means jobpost will be show

```
@foreach($query as $querys )
    <?php
        $value_salary_min  = $querys['salary_min'];
        $value_salary_max  = $querys['salary_max'];
        $avg               = ($value_salary_min + $value_salary_max )/2
        $avg               = $avg >= $salary? "display:block" : "display:none";
    ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Code in my question is the part of big and complex search query, so I can not use your approach, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

bro, I have another one solution

make a new column for **Avg** in table and when you are insert data make average salary calculation store that value in **Avg** column.

now easy to compare your **Avg** value and get a search result.

like

```
$salary = 100000;
$query = JobPost::whereRaw('Avg' ,' >=', $salary)->getQuery();
```

**Avg** your new column name and **$salary** is your variable

try this logic bro